# Anyway to optimize a large (127K) reading english words txt file

Tags: java, arrays, time

This is my function:

```
public void addToList() throws IOException {
    String urlString = "http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106l/cs106l.1102/assignments/dictionary.txt";
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    Scanner scannerWords = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    while (scannerWords.hasNextLine()) {
        words.add(scannerWords.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Which takes:
32.8 sec runtime to get executed.

Anyway I can optimize it (maybe read every 10 lines)?

Comment: You should measure which part takes that long. I would argue that the loop which adds the lines to the list is not the time consuming part. Then again, neither is transferring a 127kb file.

Comment: @f1sh it is.
The while loop is the consuming part.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any problem. Running this code takes 1564ms on my machine.

Comment: unless you are using a broken custom implementation of `List`, there is no problem with this code and it runs fine.

Comment: Could you ensure that network connectivity isn't the bottleneck here ?

Comment: Should you keep it sorted?

Comment: @4EACH no just need a couple of english words from a dictionary

Comment: Try buffering the input stream - `Scanner scannerWords = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 130048));`

Comment: @Darkman took ~17 sec now 10x
I want to optimize it more.

Comment: And if you use BufferedReader? - `Scanner scannerWords = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"), 130048));`

Comment: @Darkman worse ~30 sec

Comment: You can try the given answer or use the old school way - avoid `Scanner` altogether.

Comment: I tried your code and it's less than 1 sec.  I think it's your network connection or something else.

Comment: This question is broken.  What are you trying to achieve?  How many more optimized solutions do you need to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the obvious thing is to just download the word list once and use the local copy instead of fetching it over the net every time you run your program.

You have a leak because you're never closing the stream returned by `URL.openStream()` (Same issue would exist with your current code if you changed it to use a file). That's easy to fix by adding a `scannerWords.close();` after the loop, but a better, exception-safe way is to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

I'd dispense with the `Scanner` entirely and just use a `BufferedReader`, though. Something like:

```java
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.io.*;

// ...


private List<String> readLinesFromURL(String url) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br
         = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()))) {         
        return br
            .lines()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new));
    }
}
```

Comment: Total Time: 5156ms

Comment: @4EACH 600ms (Mine) vs 900ms (OP's) on my unscientific benchmark. I suspect they're on a dialup connection or running the JVM on an abacus or something.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt.  Instead of using the Scanner, I read character by character.  This reduce the overhead and the layers of using Scanner.

```
        String urlString = "http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106l/cs106l.1102/assignments/dictionary.txt";
        InputStream stream = new URL(urlString).openStream();
        
        
        BufferedInputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] chars = new char[100];
        int index = 0;
        
        
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true){
            int c = bufferedStream.read();
            if (c == '\n'){
                words.add(new String(chars, 0, index));
                index=0;
            } else if (c < 0){
                words.add(new String(chars, 0, index));
                break;
            } else {
                chars[index++]  = (char) c;
            }
        }
        long currentTimeMillis1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        stream.close();
        
        System.out.println("Time       = " + (currentTimeMillis1-currentTimeMillis) + " ms");
        System.out.println("Word count = " + words.size());
        System.out.println( "First word = "  +  words.get(0));
        System.out.println( "Last word  = " + words.get(words.size()-1));

    }
```

Output

```
run:
Time       = 707 ms
Word count = 127142
First word = aa
Last word  = zyzzyvas
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Character by character is going to be horrible. You should absolutely use a buffered stream of some sort otherwise you're going to be wasting a bunch of time on system calls. (Though it's possible the url returns a buffered stream.)

Comment: @matt you are right.  It seems to improve performance when is witch it to a buffered input stream.

Comment: It's something of a rule of thumb. I tried it, with a BufferedInputStream, InputStreamReader and BufferedReader and got about the same amount of time as you.

Comment: I get about 100% improvement using buffered stream on average.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch all data together
2. Apply your filter to get the expected words

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       printWords(new ArrayList<>(150000));
    }

  private static void printWords(List<String> list) throws IOException {
        final long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String urlString = "http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106l/cs106l.1102/assignments/dictionary.txt";
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        final long l2;
        final long l3;
        Charset encoding=Charset.defaultCharset();
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream(), String.valueOf(encoding))) {
            l2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            list = Arrays.asList(content.split("\\n"));
            l3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //System.out.println(list);
        }
        final long l4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(String.format("Total Time: %d",l4-l));
        System.out.println(String.format("Data fetching Time: %d",l2-l));
        System.out.println(String.format("Data collection Time: %d",l3-l2));
    }
```

##### Output:

```
Total Time: 2482
Data fetching Time: 465
Data collection Time: 2017
```

Comment: No good, still takes long I dpn't need specific filtering.

Comment: Try to pre-define initial capacity.